# connection error in java to server's postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql

it works fine when connecting to my local Postgresql database.

I used putty to map my local port 5300 to the sever port 5432.

How I filled the form is in the two pictures(unable to upload pictures directly).

[putty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGJIF.png)

[port mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUYYd.png)

And the java code is:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5300/database", "root", "123");
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    System.out.println("open database successfully");

    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from table";

    stmt.execute(sql);
    stmt.close();
    conn.commit();
    conn.close();
}
```

error log is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection Failed
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:275)
at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:194)
at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:431)
at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:247)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
at ConnectDB.main(FindFeature.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.readMore(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:140)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.ensureBytes(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:109)
at org.postgresql.core.VisibleBufferedInputStream.read(VisibleBufferedInputStream.java:67)
at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:282)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:418)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:222)
... 12 more
```

Comment: Seems as you have 5400 as port not 5300.

Comment: Have you put you port in hosts?

Comment: The question is not clear. Where's your Postgre DB located (on a local or remote server)?. Even when it's on a remote server, the port will still be 5432 (unless you explicitly changed it). The URL suggests that you're connection locally to your DB.

Comment: corrected that error. (Actually it doesn't matter because I've tried many times and this time I just mistyped.)

Comment: the Postgre DB is located on a remote server. And I suppose that if I map my local port 5300 to remote server port 5432, I will connect to the remote server port 5432 even I write as 'localhost:5300'.